# How to split the values and mark them in order from the first row, and if it's duplicate, do not mark duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**How to split the values and mark them in order from the first row, and if it's duplicate, do not mark duplicate**

There is a dataframe have three columns: **model, order, and item**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'model':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],
           'order':['aa/ab','aa/ab','aa/ab','aa/ab','aa/ab','ba','ba','ba','ba','ca/cab/cc','ca/cb/cc','ca/cb/cc','ca/cb/cc','ca/cb/cc'],
           'Item':['tissue','paper','tea_spon','chopstick','dish','horse','dog','cat','cat','tv','radio','audio','handphone','recoder']})
```

order column values, it is generally one but, but it may be combined into two or more.
In this case, it can be separated by ***"/"***.

For example, ***"aa/ab"*** means that the order ***"aa"*** and the order ***"ab"*** are combined.

[image]

[image]

If there is 1 order(like ba) per model, I want to display only the first row, and delete the rest,

If there are 2 orders(like aa/ab), only the first order is displayed in the first row, and only the second order is displayed in the second row like below picture

If it's 3 orders, you can mark it with the same rule

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your original df as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with a custom function:

```
def split(g):
    l = g.iloc[0].split('/')
    return pd.Series(l, index=g.index[:len(l)])
    
df['order'] = df.groupby('model')['order'].transform(split)
```

Output:

```
   model order       Item
0      A    aa     tissue
1      A    ab      paper
2      A   NaN   tea_spon
3      A   NaN  chopstick
4      A   NaN       dish
5      B    ba      horse
6      B   NaN        dog
7      B   NaN        cat
8      B   NaN        cat
9      C    ca         tv
10     C    cb      radio
11     C    cc      audio
12     C   NaN  handphone
13     C   NaN    recoder
```

Comment: There was an error in the question, but you understood it wisely and gave me the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Use custom lambda function in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for split values with remove duplicates:

```
f = lambda x: (pd.Series(x.str.split('/').explode().to_numpy()[:len(x)])
                 .mask(lambda x: x.duplicated()))
df['order'] = df.groupby('model')['order'].transform(f)
```

Another idea:

```
f = lambda x: (pd.Series(n:=np.unique([z for y in x for z in y.split('/')]), 
                         index=x.index[:len(n)]).reindex(x.index))
df['order'] = df.groupby('model')['order'].transform(f)

print(df)
   model order       Item
0      A    aa     tissue
1      A    ab      paper
2      A   NaN   tea_spon
3      A   NaN  chopstick
4      A   NaN       dish
5      B    ba      horse
6      B   NaN        dog
7      B   NaN        cat
8      B   NaN        cat
9      C    ca         tv
10     C    cb      radio
11     C    cc      audio
12     C   NaN  handphone
13     C   NaN    recoder
```

Comment: There was an error in the question, but you understood it wisely and gave me the right answer